# Spark - Column expression

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I came across the following express, I know what does it mean - department("name"). I am curious to know, what it is resolved to. please share your inputs .

`department("name")` - it is used to refer the column with the name "name". Hope I am correct ? But , what it is resolved to, it seems like auxiliary constructor

From https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html,

```
// To create Dataset[Row] using SparkSession
   val people = spark.read.parquet("...")
   val department = spark.read.parquet("...")

   people.filter("age > 30")
     .join(department, people("deptId") === department("id"))
     .groupBy(department("name"), people("gender"))
     .agg(avg(people("salary")), max(people("age")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`department("name")` is just syntactic sugar for calling `apply` function:

`department.apply("name")` which returns `Column`

from Spark API, `Dataset` object:

```
/**
   * Selects column based on the column name and returns it as a [[Column]].
   *
   * @note The column name can also reference to a nested column like `a.b`.
   *
   * @group untypedrel
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  def apply(colName: String): Column = col(colName)
```